# Simple jquery click event script, its a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, mouseevent

I have a simple jQuery script. This is the script:

```
var menu = $('#nav .menu');

$('li', menu).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideUp();
});
```

This script open a submenu. But i have a problem with this script. If you go over it quickly. The script launch every time. When you go over the item verry quickly. The menu open a lot of times. How can i fix this?

Thank for help

Comment: You would cache `'.sub-menu'` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use jQuery's [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function.  Passing in the necessary arguments ex. `.stop(true,true)`,`.stop(true)`

```
$('li', menu).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').stop().slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').stop().slideUp();
});
```

or passing this as the context seems a little neater to me - it does the same thing as .find()

```
$('li', menu).mouseenter(function() {
    $('.sub-menu',this).stop().slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.sub-menu',this).stop().slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$('#nav .menu li').hover(function() {
   $('.submenu').stop().slideDown();
}, function(){
   $('.submenu').stop().slideUp();
});
```